# Creating threads, assigning functions to it in a loop and executing

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have some work that needs to be done in separate threads, the work is done on a `std::vector<T>` of objects.

I need to do the work and then in the main thread, wait on all the threads with a `join()`.

I have done this the following way, but I think this isn't a good idea, as I have only one pointer, and it points to something else each iteration of the loop.

```
struct properties 
{
    explicit properties(someobj obj) : obj_(obj) {}
    void operator()() { /*do something*/ } 
    someobj obj_;
};

boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> t;
for (size_t tst = 0; tst <= myvector.size() - 1; ++tst) 
{ 
    properties props(myvector[tst]);
    t = boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread>(new boost::thread(props));

} 

//get main thread to wait till all t's are done, however is this a smart way to wait on multiple t's?? Which t is it going to wait on?
t->join();
```

Can anybody suggest a better way of doing this?  Should I make a `vector<boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread>>` and loop through them and through my object vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a thread pool. Boost might provide one, though I don't think it does. PPL and TBB provide them in their `parallel_for_each` functions.

Loosely, the `thread_group` class provided by Boost should be what you need.

Fundamentally, `boost::thread` is a wrapper on the OS thread, it's not really a solid threading base. PPL and TBB provide parallel algorithms and data structures, which is much better to go.

Comment: I second this. If you are able to use C++11 you might also want to look into the concurrency stuff in there.